# ng-if breaks grid when creating child scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a grid build with packery and I need to add two classes to every element in the grid based on some condition. I'm using ng-if to add them and it works fine, but whenever I do it the grid won't load. I believe its got something to do with the child scope ng-if is creating, but I don't know whats the work around this.

HTML:

```
    <div class="columnWidth rowHeight">

      <div class="gutter"></div>
      <div ng-repeat="shot in shots track by shot.id">

        <img
          id="{{ shot.id }}"
          ng-src="{{ shot.images.normal }}"
          class="itemSelector" ng-class="itemClass(shot.id)"
          ng-if="activeUser" draggable starable>

        <img
          id="{{ shot.id }}"
          ng-src="{{ shot.images.normal }}"
          class="itemSelector" ng-class="itemClass(shot.id)"
          ng-if="!activeUser">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
  $scope.activeUser = true;
});
```

Directives:

```
angular.module('board.directives', [])

  .directive('packeryGrid', ['$rootScope', '$window', function ($rootScope, $window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',

      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        angular.element(document).ready(function () {

          scope.$watch('board', function () {
            $rootScope.packery = new Packery(element[0], {
              itemSelector: '.itemSelector',
              columnWidth: '.columnWidth',
              rowHeight: '.rowHeight',
              gutter: '.gutter'
            });

          });

        });
      }
    };
  }])

  .directive('draggable', ['$rootScope', 'api', function ($rootScope, api) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var draggable = new Draggabilly(element[0]);
        $rootScope.packery.bindDraggabillyEvents(draggable);
        $rootScope.packery.layout();
      }
    };
  }])

  .directive('starable', ['$rootScope', 'api', function ($rootScope, api) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('dblclick', function () {
          element.toggleClass('itemSelectorBig');
          api.board().one('starred-shot', attrs.id).put();
          $rootScope.packery.layout();
        });

      }
    }
  }]);
```

Full code: http://plnkr.co/edit/cx9oJtNnRusKZrHrMipS?p=info
Thanks!

Comment: use `ng-show`. `ng-show` does not create child scope like `ng-if` does

Comment: the thing with ng-show is that it breaks the grid but in a different way. any ideas about what should be done to get ng-if working as its supposed to?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you shouldn't depend on whether some tag creates a scope for you.

Don't use activeUser it is not qualified.

Instead, you need to put it in some object, like

```
$scope.something = {};
$scope.something.activeUser = ....
```

Then when you reference it, you can use

```
{{ something.activeUser }}
```

or

```
ng-if="!something.activeUser"
```

without any danger of anyone clobbering your variables.

Comment: could you write an example of how to implement this? thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: It should be self explanatory in my answer.

Comment: i've changed it for this: `$scope.smt.activeUser = true;` and then: `ng-if="{{smt.activeUser}}" draggable starable` but the result is still the same

Comment: Don't know if your plunkr works but create the object first (see answer) and shouldn't your if be ! (not) smt.activeUser ?

Comment: yeah, thats how i builded it. it has to be true. it should work either way anyway..

Comment: check your console, you need to explain what error you are getting.